# Automatically generate list of tor exit nodes

Tags: python, tor

I want to automatically generate a list of tor exit nodes that can reach a certain IP address. I scoured the internetfor a while and came across this piece of code from http://sjoerd-hemminga.com/blog/2012/10/block-tor-exit-nodes-using-iptables/

```
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
  echo Usage: $0 "<your host's ip>"
  exit 1
fi

hostip=$1

for i in $(wget https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py\?ip=$hostip -O- -q |\
    grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+){3}$'); do
  sudo iptables -A INPUT -s "$i" -j DROP
done
```

Can someone please help me understand this code better, because every time I try to run it, it produces errors.

Any alternate answers are welcomed but I would like if they are in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
import re
import sys
import urllib

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage {} <your host's ip>".format(sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

hostip = sys.argv[1]

u = urllib.urlopen('https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=' + hostip)
for ip in u:
    ip = ip.strip()
    if re.match('\d+(\.\d+){3}$', ip):
        #print ip
        os.system('sudo iptables -A INPUT -s "{}" -j DROP'.format(ip))
u.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured Tor to have a control port and server descriptors...

```
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
UseMicrodescriptors 0
```

... then you can easily enumerate the exits using [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/)...

```
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()

  for desc in controller.get_server_descriptors():
    if desc.exit_policy.is_exiting_allowed():
      print desc.address
```

That said, if your real question is 'how do I do something using every Tor exit' then please don't! Repeatedly making circuits is harmful to the Tor network, for more about about this see [stem's FAQ](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/RD17/DeTor)(https://github.com/RD17/DeTor) is a simple REST API to determine whether a request was made from TOR network or not.

The request is:
`curl -X GET http://detor.ambar.cloud/`.

The response is 

`{ 
  "sourceIp": "104.200.20.46",
  "destIp": "89.207.89.82",
  "destPort": "8080",
  "found": true 
}`